# How to prevent serial port continuous scanning in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have honeywell barcode and use python to read barcode as serial.

Scanning one barcode after another is not an issue. The real issue is if there is another barcode near the one to be scanned. Barcode scanner keep beeping according to number of barcode it scanned and having part of `self.serial.read` to append the barcode that it scan.

After scan a barcode, my app will pass the barcode string to web api and display on tkinter gui. Below is the data received function in my class:-

```py
def serial_port_data_received(self):
    if self.serial != None:
        if self.serial.inWaiting() > 0 and self.is_requesting_data = False:
            try:
                self.is_requesting_data = True
                bytedata = bytes()
                bytedata += self.serial.read(self.serial.inWaiting())
                barcodehex = bytedata.hex()
                barcodeascii = bytedata.decode('ascii')
                barcodedata = bytedata.decode('utf-8')
                log.logger.info('barcodeno:' + barcodedata.strip())
                log.logger.info('barcodeascii:' + barcodeascii)
                log.logger.info('barcodehex:' + barcodehex)
                self.show_product_info(barcodedata)
            except TypeError as error:
                log.logger.error(error)
    self.after(1, self.serial_port_data_received)
```

Log data:-

```
INFO [myapp.py.serial_port_data_received:180] barcodehex:393738303230323335303434380d393738303230343737373439360d393738303230353236323930380d393738303230353734383331300d393738303230333332313236330d393738303230343239323038310d
INFO [myapp.py.request_product_info:72] http://domain.company.com/api/default/getproductinfo, payload: {'barcodeno': '9780202350448\r9780204777496\r9780205262908\r9780205748310\r9780203321263\r9780204292081\r'}
DEBUG [connectionpool.py._new_conn:226] Starting new HTTP connection (1): domain.company.com:80
DEBUG [connectionpool.py._make_request:433] http://domain.company.com:80 "POST /api/default/getproductinfo?barcodeno=9780202350448%0D9780204777496%0D9780205262908%0D9780205748310%0D9780203321263%0D9780204292081%0D HTTP/1.1" 401 4
INFO [myapp.py.request_product_info:87] [!] HTTP 401 calling [api/default/getproductinfo]
INFO [myapp.py.show_product_info:102] No Response Found
INFO [myapp.py.serial_port_data_received:178] barcodeno:9780202350448
9780205262908
9780202835853
9780205748310
9780203321263
INFO [myapp.py.serial_port_data_received:179] barcodeascii:9780202350448
9780205262908
9780202835853
9780205748310
9780203321263

INFO [myapp.py.serial_port_data_received:180] barcodehex:393738303230323335303434380d393738303230353236323930380d393738303230323833353835330d393738303230353734383331300d393738303230333332313236330d
INFO [myapp.py.request_product_info:72] http://domain.company.com/api/default/getproductinfo, payload: {'barcodeno': '9780202350448\r9780205262908\r9780202835853\r9780205748310\r9780203321263\r'}
DEBUG [connectionpool.py._new_conn:226] Starting new HTTP connection (1): domain.company.com:80
DEBUG [connectionpool.py._make_request:433] http://domain.company.com:80 "POST /api/default/getproductinfo?barcodeno=9780202350448%0D9780205262908%0D9780202835853%0D9780205748310%0D9780203321263%0D HTTP/1.1" 401 4
INFO [myapp.py.request_product_info:87] [!] HTTP 401 calling [api/default/getproductinfo]
INFO [myapp.py.show_product_info:102] No Response Found
INFO [myapp.py.serial_port_data_received:178] barcodeno:9780205748310
INFO [myapp.py.serial_port_data_received:179] barcodeascii:9780205748310

INFO [myapp.py.serial_port_data_received:180] barcodehex:393738303230353734383331300d
INFO [myapp.py.request_product_info:72] http://domain.company.com/api/default/getproductinfo, payload: {'barcodeno': '9780205748310\r'}
DEBUG [connectionpool.py._new_conn:226] Starting new HTTP connection (1): domain.company.com:80
DEBUG [connectionpool.py._make_request:433] http://domain.company.com:80 "POST /api/default/getproductinfo?barcodeno=9780205748310%0D HTTP/1.1" 401 4
INFO [myapp.py.request_product_info:87] [!] HTTP 401 calling [api/default/getproductinfo]
INFO [myapp.py.show_product_info:102] No Response Found
```

The end of scanned barcode is `CR` or `0D` or `\r`. How do I limit the serial reading to discard any other data after first **CR** is exist? Or do I need to disable scanner after having first data?

I have tried several way by using flag `self.is_requesting_data` and only set it to False after Display /Show record not found GUI.

I have my previous code with same behaviour if multiple barcode near the one to be scanned:-

```py
def serial_port_data_received(self):
    if self.serial != None:
        rx = []
        while (self.serial.inWaiting() > 0 and self.is_requesting_data == False):
            self.data_left = self.serial.inWaiting()
            print('data_left: ' + str(self.data_left))
            rx.append(ord(self.serial.read(1)))
            time.sleep(0.001)

        if rx != [] and self.is_requesting_data == False:
            for s in rx:
                data_ascii = '%c' % s
                self.barcodelist.append(data_ascii)
                if data_ascii != b'':
                    self.barcodestring += data_ascii
            if self.barcodelist[-1] == b'' and self.is_requesting_data == False:
                barcodeno = self.barcodestring.strip()
                print('Barcode: ' + self.barcodestring)
                self.barcodestring = ''
                self.is_requesting_data = True
                self.show_product_info(barcodeno.strip())
    self.after(1, self.serial_port_data_received)
```

[image]

Comment: You `split()` the data and take the first (or which ever you prefer) only?

Comment: I prefer take the first data with `0D` and discard all data from `0D` onwards. Though having a flag `self.is_requesting_data == False` is not working. It still continue read. And because of it, the UI become unsorted because it keep destroy the widget children and recreate and call idle function to create another GUI.